# Angular2 routing don't know where to put router output

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm using angular2 rc4 version. I have 3 components.

**AppComponent**: Here, in the `app.component.html` file I render another component named `HomeComponent` with selector `<app-home></app-home>`

**HomeComponent**: Here, in the `home.component.html` file there are some contents and a link to `Dashboard`.

```
<a class="page-scroll" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
```

**DashboardComponent**: here in the `dashboard.component.html` file some content.

In my `main.ts` file I've declared my routes and import my necessary components. Code snippet:

```
import { provideRouter, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './app/dashboard/dashboard.component';


const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', terminal: true },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }

];

bootstrap(AppComponent, provideRouter(routes));
```

Now the problem. I paste `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in my `home.component.html` file and then clicked on the `dashboard` link. It renders the `dashboard.component.html` but the contents of `home.component.html` file was still in the `root-url/dashboard` page.

If i put `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in top of `home.component.html` file then after clicking dashboard `dashboard.component.html` contents shows first, then shows `home.componet.html` contents. If i put `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in bottom of `home.component.html` file then after clicking dashboard `home.component.html` contents shows first, then shows `dashboard.componet.html` contents.

What I want is, clicking on the `dashboard` link will only show dashboard contents. How am I supposed to do that? As I'm a newbie I m unable to figure that out on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `<router-outlet>` in `app.component`

**working demo** : https://plnkr.co/edit/hXJ6ZRv81kt4rvWhxoBD?p=preview

```
import { provideRouter, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './app/dashboard/dashboard.component';


const routes: RouterConfig = [

  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', terminal: true },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardCompnent}

];

bootstrap(AppComponent, provideRouter(routes));
```

and in **home.component**

```
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="page-scroll" (click)="redirect()">Dashboard</a>


constructor(private router: Router) {}
redirect()
{
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
}
```

Comment: It's working (+1). But main url should be defined as `{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },`. Is this the only solution? Because, then why angular2 team put `routerlink` concept then?

Comment: Routelink is there for navigation and updates your current view and inject new template into `router-outlet`. Here you want to update whole page and not only the part of page. so you have to put `router-outlet` in app.component.

Comment: @Emu : wrt your first comment, even I want the answer to be like that, but no finding so far! :(  (P.S.: I am also a newbie)

Comment: can't i use <router-outlet> in index.html instead of app.component.html

Comment: Nope you can't use it @RahulKumar